# Distribution group external sender and contacts

Tags: exchange, exchange-2019

we have a distribution group on our exchange server 2019 with some external contacts in it.
Receiving of external mails is activated for this group.
Now if an external sender sens a mail to this distribution group he gets a "unable to relay" message from our exchange for the mails that should be forwarded to the external contacts. Of course this is coming up because our exchange server does not allow the relaying of external mail addresses.
Is there any clever way for allowing this on exchange server?
Thanks and best regards

Comment: Do above suggestion work for you? If your issue has been resolved, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer or share your solution, your action will be helpful to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research, you may create a mail flow rule to redirect mails from external senders to internal users, and then enable forward feature for the internal user to forward these mails to distribution group. Therefore, see the message as coming from an internal address.

Rules can be configured as below:

1. create a mail flow rule to redirect mails to internal user:
   [image]
2. enable forward feature for the internal user to forward mails to distribution group:
   [image]
   [image]